# Exception throws when calling jar

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven-jar-plugin

I have a class and I use

```
String signingAlgorithm = SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256.toString();
```

there. class works fine when I running `unit test` or `main method`. But it gives this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/SigningAlgorithm

when I call `jar`

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
     <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I use `maven-jar-plugin`

```
<manifest>
     <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
     <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
     <mainClass>com.example.my.MainClass</mainClass>
</manifest>
```

any idea?

Comment: You need to have the AWS jar file (and maybe other dependencies) somewhere, maybe in `lib/` under the current directory. I recommend building a jar-with-dependencies that bundles them all to simplify deployment.

Comment: ya. I have the `aws-java-sdk` in maven dependencies. version `1.7.2`

Comment: that won't automatically put them into the jar file. But it could be something else. Do you have the full stacktrace?

Comment: yeah, looks like a dependency jar is missing. If your manifest says `lib/aws.jar` you need to have that jar file in addition to your own. It won't load it magically from the Maven repo.

Comment: @Thilo `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/SigningAlgorithm
 at com.example.my.SignatureUtil.getEncoded(SignatureUtil.java:85)
 at com.example.my.SignatureUtil.generateSignature(SignatureUtil.java:50)
 at com.example.my.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.SigningAlgorithm
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)`

Comment: you mean, adding `aws-java-sdk` dependency won't just do the job. do I need to keep seperate `aws' jar with may project jar?

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for your help. I follow this answer to package deps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven